# How can I make an infinite generator in Python to all prime numbers?

Tags: python, generator, infinite-loop

I was trying to make this infinite generator in Python:

```py
import math
def all_primes():
    count = 2
    while True:
        flag = True
        for x in range(2, int(math.sqrt(count) + 1)):
            if count % x == 0:
                flag = False

        if flag:
            yield count
        else:
            count += 1

for i in all_primes():
    print(i)
```

but in the output it always gives me 2. Why is that?

Comment: You need to increment `count` no matter if it is a prime or not.

Comment: when do you expect the output (`count`) to change, and why do you think it should happen?

Comment: BTW 2 is a prime number too!

Comment: At some point in an infinite generator, it's probably more efficient to switch to a better [primality test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primality_test) than trial division.

Comment: I was going to add 2 after getting it to work

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't augment count after finding a prime, so you're always returning the same value (3).

Your prime generator is going to take longer and longer between each prime as you move forward.

Here's an infinite prime generator that is more efficient.  It is inspired from the sieve of Eratosthenes, but it uses a dictionary to only propagate multiples as it reaches a non-prime number and moves the prime multiple to the next multiple that hasn't been flagged as non-prime yet:

```
def genPrimes():
    yield 2                      # get the first prime out of the way
    skips      = dict()          # multiples to skip {Multiple:2xPrime}
    multiples  = ((p*p,2*p) for p in genPrimes()) # multiples of primes
    skipMark,_ = next(multiples)                  # skipping coverage
    N = 1                        # prime candidate (odd numbers)
    while True:
       N += 2                        # next prime candidate
       if N >= skipMark:                     # extend skips coverage
           skipMark,stride = next(multiples) # 1st multiple and stride
           skips[skipMark] = stride
       if N in skips:                # not a prime (multiple of a prime)
           stride   = skips.pop(N)   # get prime multiple steps
           multiple = N + stride     # advance skip to next multiple
           while multiple in skips:
               multiple += stride    # not already skipped
           skips[multiple] = stride
       else:                         # N is prime
           yield N                   # return it
```

Output:

```python
for p in genPrimes(): print(p)
```

```
2
3
5
7
11
13
17
19
23
29
31
37
41
43
47
53
59
...
```

*The skips dictionary contains roughly one entry per √P (where P is the number of primes found so far) and doesn't require pre-allocating memory.  This approach trades space for a gain in time.*

Comment: If you want so save memory as well, try making that a recursive generator that doesn't store the prime squares so far in advance :-) (I have a few versions [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/251178/219610))

Answer (score 1):

The reason your code is always yielding '3' is that 'flag' is always true. Working through the math in the for loop with int(math.sqrt(count)+1) makes it so the loop only goes from 2 -> 2. So the only thing checked is if 3 % 2 == 0 which is never true. Therefore flag is always false and the count is never incremented.

Answer (score 1):

That’s because the *for* loop is never iterating. If count=3 then `int(math.sqrt(count) + 1)` is going to return 2, so the range of your *for* loop is going to be (2,2). Therefore it will never iterate, and the flag value is not going to change, and therefore count value is always going to be the same.

Answer (score -3):

Here is a prime generator i created using Wilson's theorem. We can calculate a running factorial benefitting from python-3's unlimited integers. :-)

```
# find primes p>2 using Wilson's theorem: (p-2)! = 1(mod p)
n = int(input("Input the number of prime numbers you want to generate (at least 2)? "))
from time import time
t = time()
p,m,f = 2,2,1
Primes = [1,2]
while m<n:
    p += 1
    f = f*(p-2)         
    if (f-p*(f//p))==1: 
        m += 1
        Primes.append(p)
print (Primes)
print ('{} primes generated in {} seconds'.format(n,time()-t))
```

Comment: This is not a Python generator: you are just putting the prime numbers in a list. Please edit the code to make a proper generator (i.e. a function using the yield keyword).

Comment: OP is asking a question about _their_ code. Dumping a completely different implementation into an answer isn't very helpful. Please read [answer]. In particular, please make sure that the answers you post address the question being asked.

Comment: Quick note: [answers which misunderstood the question are **not** Very Low Quality.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/272925/are-answers-which-misunderstood-the-question-low-quality) The proper review for this is "Looks OK". (If you feel that the answer is not useful, feel free to downvote).